# Previous Matches in Global RegEx Preventing Adjacent Overlapping Matches

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to find **all** occurrences of a character surrounded by whitespace on at least one side. I also want to include the spaces in my match. Additionally, I want to doubly count the spaces if there are more than one adjacent match.

RegEx: `/(\s*\w\s*)/g`

Sample Data: `a  b  c  d  e  f  g`

Actual Result: `["  b  ","  d  ","  f  "]`

Desired Result:  `["a  ","  b  ","  c  ", "  d  ","  e  ","  f  ","  g"]`

I've taken a look at several other similar SO questions, which mostly point to using lookaround groups. I've tried a few attempts at lookarounds, but not sure how to address the overlapping spaces while still capturing them. I'm trying to avoid using capture groups, because of a requirement to capture each *separately* as an array. For context, I'm using a JavaScript-based regex engine.

Is there a way to capture *all* matches of a RegEx globally, even for matches that adjacent and overlap?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I fully understand your needs, but I would suggest to try this pattern:

```js
let pattern = /(\s?\w\s?)/g

console.log(("a  b  c  d  e  f  g").match(pattern))
```

It matches a letter and a space on each side, if there is one (including the overlapping ones).

Answer (score 1):

lookarounds don't match the character itself, so if we need to capture it this way, we should capture the character separately. One way to do this would be:

```js
const text = "a  b  c  d  e  f  g";
const regex = /(?:(?<=\s)\s|)\w(?:(?=\s)\s|)/g
console.log(text.match(regex))
```

This uses positive lookbehind in the first section and positive lookahead in the second section. (positive lookbeghind may not be supported everywhere).

this is kind of a `if else` statement:

- if there's is whitespace before alphabetic character: `(?:(?<=\s)`
- include that: `\s`
- else anything else would count: `|`

Answer (score 1):

You might you a negative lookbehind to assert what is directly to the left is not a whitespace char.

Then could use a capturing group inside a lookahead to assert this pattern `\s*\w\s*` directly at the right.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
(?<!\s)(?=(\s*\w\s*))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNQ20a/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<!\s)(?=(\s*\w\s*))/g;
const str = `a  b  c  d  e  f  g`;
let m;
let result = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  result.push(m[1]);

}
console.log(result);
```